# how to enable or disable multiple different functions easily in bash?

Tags: bash, function

I would like to run some different functions in bash. But not everytime I would run all the functions. So I want to do a simple switch in the beginning of my bash script to enable/disable my functions.

Here is my first thought:

```
enable_fun_A=true
enable_fun_B=false

if [ "$enable_fun_A" = true ]; then
    fun_A
fi

if [ "$enable_fun_B" = true ]; then
    fun_B
fi
```

I would like to know if there exists a smart way to deal with enable/disable functions in bash script?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with this one? And what way do you like to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the `if` condition by maintaining a flag like below

```
enable_flag=0

function fun_A {
    ((enable_flag)) && return 0
    echo "Inside the function"
}

fun_A
enable_flag=1
fun_A
```

Comment: So by avoiding the `if` condition you mean moving it to the function `fun_a`

Comment: I guess this way, even if the function is called, it can be controlled by a flag, not sure if this is what the OP meant

Comment: @andlrc: Suggestions/improvements on the answer appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @Inian. Your method is simple than mine. In short I expected something similar to enable/disable echo in bash script. This method is pretty much closer to the method.